# Reference a dataframe from a list in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes to which I'd like to add a new column containing the year. Rather than doing this one at a time I'd like to use a for loop and a list to reference them.

Here is my code (list reduced in size to save space here):

> my.list
>       <- list("Accounting.and.Finance",
>               "Aeronautical.and.Manufacturing.Engineering",
>               "Agriculture.and.Forestry",
>               "American.Studies")
>
> for(i in 1:length(my.list)){my.list[[i]]$Year <- 2016}

Unfortunately, rather than adding the Year column to each dataframe, it is giving me the following warnings:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In subject.list[[i]]$Year <- 2016 : Coercing LHS to a list
>
> 2: In subject.list[[i]]$Year <- 2016 : Coercing LHS to a list
>
> 3: In subject.list[[i]]$Year <- 2016 : Coercing LHS to a list
>
> 4: In subject.list[[i]]$Year <- 2016 : Coercing LHS to a list

and adding $Year to the list. Can anyone offer any advice on how I should be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: `my.list` is a list of character vectors and not a list of data.frames. Maybe without the quotes? `my.list <- list(Accounting.and.Finance, Aeronautical.and.Manufacturing.Engineering, Agriculture.and.Forestry, American.Studies)`

Comment: Thanks Roland. That adds a year column to each dataframe within the list, but not to the original individual dataframes. Any thoughts on how to then use that list to update the individual dataframes?

Comment: There is no reason to do that. Those data.frames should be together in a list to begin with. Maybe they even should be combined into one data.frame.

Comment: OK, I see what I need to do now; work with the dataframes in the list and then I can write them out to .csv files from the list. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your example was difficult to use so I re-built it,

```
my.list <- list(
Accounting.and.Finance  <- data.frame(A=seq(1,10), B=seq(11,20),C=seq(21,30)),
Aeronautical.and.Manufacturing.Engineering  <- data.frame(A=seq(1,10), B=seq(11,20),C=seq(21,30)),
Agriculture.and.Forestry  <- data.frame(A=seq(1,10), B=seq(11,20),C=seq(21,30)),
American.Studies  <- data.frame(A=seq(1,10), B=seq(11,20),C=seq(21,30))
)
```

which can be used to add the year column using the lapply function,

```
my.list  <- lapply(my.list, cbind, Year=seq(2001,2010))
```